# How Do I Evaluate My Self Trained MATCONNET CNN network

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

I am trying to build my own CNN (Alexnet Model) for traffic sign recognition using MATCONVNET. I used the image dataset from the German Traffic Sign Recognition Benchmark (GTSRB) website (http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=datase) to create my own IMDB which consists of well-labeled training, validation and test data for 43 classes of road traffic signs.

Now I am having two challenges.

1. My network is not converging. I have an about steady error of 0.977
2. I am trying to evaluate my trained network even with this error rate, but thats where I have my biggest challenge. I havent been able to figure out how to evaluate self trainined networks in MATCONVNET and there are very little helpful materials out there to help.

Someone please help out if you have an idea on what I need to change or do better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with MATCONVNET in particular so I may be misinterpreting your issue, but a general rule for evaluating classifiers is cross-validate (i.e. train and test on different subsets and repeat across multiple subset configurations).

### For one configuration

To generate one configuration of data you can use

```
nObservations = size(data,1);
y_act = ... ; % class labels for each observation
ratio = .5; 
net = ... %your net definition

[Train,Test] = crossvalind('HoldOut',nObservations,ratio);
[net,...] = train(net,data(Train,:))
y_exp = predict(net,data(Test,:))
rate = length(find(y_exp == y_act(Test)))/...
       numel(y_act(Test));
```

Rate is a better indicator than your original one. Depending on your model, you probably want to make sure that the classes are distributing at an even proportion (or maybe even equal amounts, which would require you to toss some observations so you have equal class totals). To ensure this you can divide each class independently with `crossvalind` and then merge to form your Train/Test sets.

You can also play around with your train:test ratio. .5 is a fine place to start. Gradually increase if you have trouble classifying your test set.

### Permute configurations

One issue with this analysis is only evaluates one configuration. For massive datasets or sets where generalization is not important that might be ok. But you can combat this by permutating the above analysis across

1. all combinations within a set configuration

   Say you divide the dataset into A,B,C, and D. You can   train([A,B,C])-test(D), train(A,B,D)-test(C), ... train(B,C,D)-test(A) and average the prediction rates

   This is usually 'good enough' but you have to acknowledge that in small datasets you could have a skewed representations in one of your sets
2. all possible configurations within a set

   Using `nchoosek(...)` you can represent all possible configurations and test each one for train-test. Becomes impossibly long very quickly. Choosing an arbitrary, large number of these configurations works too. If you have really low observation numbers this is useful at a low costs,especially when validated with [bootstrapping](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootstrp.html). Probably not relevant for your analysis.